# Arch Linux and windows 7: Conection to the internet on Arch trough Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, connection-sharing

There's a connection to the internet on machine with Win7 through wi-fi. Local net between these PCs is already set up. Machines ping eachother well. What about surfing internet on machine with Arch trough this local net.

Answer (score 1):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing